# Is there other ways to write this code for more flexibility

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Now, I have a list of 5 Students (example) in db with IDs are 1,2,3,4,5 in order.

In my code, I want to treat these students in many different ways by **using different functions**.

For example, Student ID 1 will be worked with the function name 'Call_History()'

Student 2 will be used for the function name 'Get_Record()'

Similar to the rest.

Here is my code:

```
if(studentID == 1) Call_History();
else if(studentID == 2) Get_Record();
else ....
```

So, with list of **10 students**, I have to **write code if...else 10 times**. What I want to ask here is: Is there any way (except using switch) to help me write code more fexibility?

Comment: `switch (studentID) { case 1: /*do something */ break; case 2: /* etc. */ }`

Comment: @Nolonar He already wrote *except using switch*

Comment: You should ask the question at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. Those guys love thise kind of questions :)

Comment: Hmm... if switch is no good, maybe events?

Comment: @Langthang You should google *Polymorphism*

Comment: If the students are in the database, hard-coding their IDs in your code base seems to be a very bad idea. Maybe your example for SO was simplified but what you do looks like you need to adapt your program very often to changes in the database. Maybe there is a way to store what to do in the database? Like an enumeration which maps an action to a operation?

Comment: The problem is that there is no real reason other then the actual hardcoded ID to do something different for the student. Your actual objects (students) seem to be too different from each other to be the same object, or maybe they have a different setting.

Comment: Why is the C# tag removed, no longer relevant?

Comment: @Matten, yes, I used enum in this case, but it force me to set up again Student ID in my code. (If I change ID in db, I must change it in code too). And I see it is not flexible, that is why I have this question. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Nanne, yes, as I said, this situation occurs when I must use different functions, and can't use design pattern for it.

Comment: You are not giving a reason, you are just stating that you cannot use "design pattern". I disagree.

Comment: @Langthang i meant an enumeration for the desired action, like 0 -> Get_Result(), ...

Comment: @Nanne, you can see my question, I put there 2 different functions: Call_History() and Get_Record(). They are different to use design pattern, right?

Comment: @Matten, can you give me a link to I can understand more enumeration like 0->Get_result(). I don't know it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

use one of the following design patterns

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern
or
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: As I said, this situation occurs when I must use different functions, and can't use design pattern for it. I think I must live with if...else command. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank Nahum. I've applied success.

Comment: @Langthang glad to help. if it indeed was the method you used. please mark it as the selected answer.

Answer (score 2):

This example is in C#, but there are similar data structures in other languages such as Java.

You could use a `Dictionary<int, Action>` which is initialised with all the action/ID combinations.

Then do something like:

```
if (actionMap.ContainsKey(studentId))
    actionMap[studentId]();
```

Comment: You use `studentId` to check then `studentKey` to call.

Answer (score 1):

use dictionary

```
Dictionary<int, delegate> allStudentsAndActions=new (...);

allStudentsAndActions.Add(1, FirstMethod);
...
allStudentsAndActions.Add(N, OtherMethod);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you need to determine the logic based on the ID of the student , you have to write the piece of the code somewhere , you can not skip it. One of the way i think is Factory pattern will also help you to make your code better and maintainable

Comment: Yes. I think I must live with if...else command. Thank you so much for your help.